# printf and backspace

Tags: vim, less, editors

I thought of playing around a bit with `find -fprintf`. In case you don't know what `-fprintf` does, it is the same as `-printf` but writing to a file you specify its name.

Now, when I run a command like this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d  -fprintf output "%p\b\n"
```

I get the following in `output` (using `vim` and pretty much any text editor):

```
.^H
./directory-1^H
./directory-2^H
./directory-3^H
```

I understand that `^H` is the backspace character. Opening `output` with `less`:

```
./directory-
./directory-
./directory-
```

So, the question is:

1. Why do `vim` and other text editors (tried `nano`, and `emacs`) display the backspace without interpreting it by removing the character before it but `less` does?
2. Why don't the editors print a character for `\n` instead of going down for a new line?
3. What is the difference between printing a backspace and hitting backspace
   on the keyboard (a character gets actually deleted on hitting backspace on the keyboard)?

I'm running this on my machine (laptop) without sshing anywhere. Using GNU/Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with konsole and tmux.

Comment: I think it's because less like more are pager and the others are editors. You can get the same display with less with the -U option.

Comment: Alright. Then why don't the editors print a character for `\n` instead of going down for a new line? And what is the difference between printing a backspace and hitting backspace on the keyboard (a character gets actually deleted on hitting backspace on the keyboard)?

Comment: Since I found this while looking for `printf` and backspace (`\b`) _without_ a file,I wanted to say the following about output on a `bash` terminal. (I didn't want `fprintf`.) Let's use printing an array within square brackets with delimiter, `, ` - python style. From my `bash` (on Cygwin, BTW), declare `arr=( 1 2 3 4 )`. First look without backspace: `printf '['; printf '%s, ' "${arr[@]}"; printf ']'` => output `[1, 2, 3, 4, ]`. If we think the comma and space (_2_ characters) are "extra", use _2_ '`\b`', i.e. `printf '['; printf '%s, ' "${arr[@]}"; printf '\b\b]'`, => output `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Note that, if I redirect this to a file using `printf '[' >> myfile; printf '%s, ' "${arr[@]}" >> myfile; printf '\b\b]' >> myfile`, I get the same behavior you do. I start with `cat myfile` (oh no! the vicious "`cat` for display"), and get `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Next, `less myfile` gives me `[1, 2, 3, 4]` (and I press [q]). Using `vim myfile`, (unless I change formatting options, e.g. by using `.vimrc`), I get `[1, 2, 3, 4, ^H^H]`. Same result with `emacs myfile` as with `vim myfile`. If you want `cat` to output in the format of `vim` and `emacs`, `cat -ETv myfile` gives output `[1, 2, 3, 4, ^H^H]`.

Answer (score 5):

> Why do vim and other text editors (tried nano, and emacs) display the backspace without interpreting it by removing the character before it but less does?

Why should they? FWIW, neither do browsers :-)

```
$ printf "<html>foo\bbar</html>" > /tmp/foo.html
$ firefox /tmp/foo.html
```

Should editors also interpret other kind of markup, like mini-Markdown `*foo*` or `**bar**`?

Notice that backspace isn't just "deleting" the previous char in `less`, but it's used as a crude formatting character. `x\bx` will print `x` in bold, and `x\b_` will underline it (which on some terminals will cause it to be printed with a different color):

```
printf "H\b_e\b_r\b_e\b_'s\bs Johnny!" | less
```

> Why don't the editors print a character for \n instead of going down for a new line?

They could do that. For instance, if you use `:set list` in `vi`, newlines will be printed as `$` and tabs as `^I`.

> What is the difference between printing a backspace and hitting backspace on the keyboard (a character gets actually deleted on hitting backspace on the keyboard)?

On a hard-type terminal (printing on paper), printing a backspace was causing the carriage to go one position to the left, so a subsequent char would *overwrite*, not delete what was already on the paper. On glass (CRT) and emulated terminals, moving a position to the left and writing a character creates an 'erase' effect because overwriting a character replaces it completely. But the `\b` by itself does not remove anything: `printf "123\b\n"` will print `123` not `12`.

The latter is a function of the tty driver, which interprets some input characters as editing/control commands (`erase`, `werase`, `intr`, `kill` -- look at the `stty(1)` or `termios(3)` manpages for the full list).

And the backspace key does **not** always generate a `\b` / `^H` (BS) character. Most of the time is `\x7f` / `^?` (DEL).

But you can set it to whatever you like:

```
$ stty erase '#'
```

Now hitting `#` will erase the previous char, like in unix v7.

Comment: For the part regarding printing `\n` instead of going down for a new line. I understand that vim displays the `\n` as `$` when `:set list`. The question is: why doesn't it display `a\nb` on a single terminal line with `\n` in the middle instead of going one line down? vim interprets `\n` as we are expecting it to, by moving down one line and not printing a character indicating the new line with the rest of the text around.

Comment: because that's the user's expectation, to have text files displayed 2-dimensionally; but you can force `vim` to display the whole file on a single line by setting the newline separator to CR as on (older?) Macs with eg. `:e ++ff=mac file`

Comment: I was wondering why I got the behavior shown in my comment to the OP. That is, why did `arr=( 1 2 3 4 ); printf '['; printf '%s, ' "${arr[@]}"; printf '\b\b]'` "erase" the ending `, `, while, as you said, **"** `printf "123\b\n"` will print `123` not `12`. **"**. I played around a bit: `printf '123\b\n'` => `123`(\n). `printf '123'; printf '\b'` => `123`. `printf '123'; printf '\b\b'; printf '\n'` => `123`(\n). `printf '123'; printf '\b'; printf ']'` =>`12]`. `printf '123\b\b]\n'` => `1]3`(\n). Some clarification, some confusion. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6792867/6505499) was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

## File contents are what applications make of them.

One of the features of the design of Unix was that files are undistinguished sequences of characters, and it is up to applications to place whatever interpretation that they like upon them.  Applications can and do interpret file contents differently, and you are experiencing the consequences of this.

VIM is interpreting the file contents in accordance with the Single Unix Specification's notion of a *Text File*, which is a file comprising zero or more lines terminated by `␊` and containing no `␀` characters.  It turns unprintable characters into various printable representations, but `␊` is always the end of a line because that is part of the concept.

Other utilities interpret file contents differently.  One family of them interprets file contents as a stream of Teletype Model 37 (TTY-37) output data.  This family comprises several conventional Unix and GNU programs: `less`, `more`, `most`, `ul`, `colcrt`, `ncal`, `grotty` in non-default mode, and others.  In this interpretation, the `␈` character moves the (conceptual) print head back one position and *overstrikes* what was there before.  Because these programs are not physical TTY-37s with ink on paper, they implement their own ideas in software of what overstriking means.  Overstriking can variously result in attempts to use boldface and underline attributes, in complete replacement of one character by another, in combined characters, or in nothing at all.

## Further reading

- ["Text files"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403).  *Base Definitions*.  Single UNIX Specification.  IEEE 1003.1.  2018.  The Open Group.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320922/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). *[An improved manual page for `ul`](http://jdebp.eu./Proposals/ul-manual-page.html)*.  Proposals.

Comment: Thanks mate for the clear answer. Needed to read that.

Comment: This is excellent. The explanation is very clear, and the sources are useful. Plus 1 for you.